# NA while using strptime function

Tags: r

RStudio Version 1.0.136
Windows Ver: Windows10 Pro X64

I input a time with quotes, and want to try the `strptime` function. I have tried a lot of formats, but always get `NA` returned, why is that?

```
t3 <- "October 17, 1986 08:24"

strptime(t3, "%M %d, %Y %H:%M")

strptime(t3, "%B %d, %Y %H:%M")

strptime(t3, "%B %d %Y %H:%M")

strptime(t3, "%M %d %Y %H:%M")

strptime(t3, "%M-%d-%Y %H:%M")

strptime(t3, "%B-%d-%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: What is the result of `Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")`?

Comment: the formats are not random, why are you trying so many combinations? The second one is correct by the way, this is like a multiple choice SAT question

Comment: I think I find the problem. I tried those in the RStudio, which gets me NA returned. So RStudio does not support this function? I used to think they would give me the same result. And by the way, would you please tell me how can I decide whether the month should be used by "B" or "M"? thanks a lot

Comment: see documentation at https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find another thread which gives me a solution. Because my system language is not English, it cannot recognize "October". After I change it to "10", the code runs perfectly. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by rawr, your second attempt is correct:

```
t3 <- "October 17, 1986 08:24"

t <- strptime(t3, "%B %d, %Y %H:%M")

str(t)
```

Results:

```
POSIXlt[1:1], format: "1986-10-17 08:24:00"
```

Comment: @rawr I really cannot get the result with this function. Here's the screenshot on my computer, with exactly the same code.[Screen Shot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1174148/R.JPG).

Answer (score 0):

```
strptime(t3,"%B %d, %Y  %H:%M")
```

from https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html